# Print map variable using heredoc stings

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to print a map variable in terraform  using heredoc example :

```
 description = <<EOT
  Hello Check ${local.map_variable1} and $local.map_variable2} 
EOT
```

my map variables are follows:

```
> local.map_variable1
{
  "server_1" = "100.100.50.101"
  "server_2" = "100.100.50.102"
  "server_3" = "100.100.50.103"
  "server_4" = "100.100.50.104"
}
> local.map_variable2
{
  "Application_node1" = "100.100.51.101"
  "Application_node2" = "100.100.52.102"
  "Application_node3" = "100.100.53.103"
  "Application_node4" = "100.100.54.104"
}
>
```

**Error**: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Any suggestion on how to print map var

Comment: What is the full context where you are using `description`? Also it should be `Hello Check ${local.map_variable1} and ${local.map_variable2} `

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. It’s ${local.map_varible2}

Comment: I’m using resource "local_file" "body " {
 filename = "config-error.txt"
 content = <<EOT 
        Hello pls check ${local.map_varible1} and ${local.map_varable2}
        world 
 EOT
}

Comment: What exactly are `local.map_varible1` and `local.map_varible2`?

Comment: @Marcin : here are the variables  ``` > local.map_variable1
{
  "server_1" = "100.100.50.101"
  "server_2" = "100.100.50.102"
  "server_3" = "100.100.50.103"
  "server_4" = "100.100.50.104"
}
> local.map_variable2
{
  "Application_node1" = "100.100.51.101"
  "Application_node2" = "100.100.52.102"
  "Application_node3" = "100.100.53.103"
  "Application_node4" = "100.100.54.104"
}
>```

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. [Accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Marcin. I'm recently joined stackoverflow

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to convert your variables into **json string** using [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsonencode):

```
description = <<EOT
  Hello Check ${jsonencode(local.map_variable1)} and ${jsonencode(local.map_variable2)} 
EOT
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly same solution for the same question in Packer coincidentally asked recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369068/how-can-print-return-object-of-data-in-packer/71370167#71370167